# Rspec - Accessing Sorcery methods/variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails, sorcery

Trying to write some tests for code I've already written, with a view to extending my code using test-driven development.

I have a controller whose index action calls a 'user_info' method, which just collects together some instance variables relying on Sorcery's current_user variable. For example:

```
def user_info
  @current_A = current_user.a
  @current_B = current_user.b
end

def index
  user_info
  // rest of the method goes here
end
```

I started writing some tests using rspec, just to get  a feel for testing this code base. My controller spec is very basic and looks like this:

```
describe MyController do
  describe "GET 'index'" do
    get 'index'
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

However, I get the following error when I try to run this spec:
    NoMethodError: undefined method 'a' for false:FalseClass

First of all, how do I get my spec to recognize the Sorcery method current_user? And, out of curiosity, why is current_user being flagged as an instance of FalseClass? If it's not calling the Sorcery method, (and I haven't defined current_user anywhere else in my code), should it not appear as nil?

Comment: Always best to accept the best answer, or to answer it yourself and accept that.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To use Sorcery test helpers you need the following lines in your `spec_helper.rb`.

The following needs to be in the Rspec.configure block:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails
end
```

After you have this in place you can use the Sorcery test helpers. For a Controller test you would add the following to your test.

```
@user = either a fixture or a factory to define the user
login_user
```

If you don't want to specify `@user` you can pass an argument.

```
login_user(fixture or factory definition)
```

Once you login the `current_user` should be available to your tests.

`logout_user` is also available.

See the [Sorcery Wiki](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/wiki/Testing-rails-3) for information on setting up a user fixture to work with the `login_user` helper.

Comment: after taking @nmott advice to add Sorcery helper in rpsec config this is working at top of my Uses controller spec - let(:user) {  
      u = FactoryGirl.create(:user) \n
      login_user(u) \n
      u
    }

Answer (score 0):

Richard, the problem is likely that you don't have a current_user.

To do that, you need to simulate the login process.

You can do that with a controller spec, but I don't have a good example here. I was writing specs on existing code, like you, and it made sense to use request specs instead.

I also don't have one for Sorcery (I should!!) and I am here using Capybara for filling in forms,. Still, here is how my spec looked:

(Here :account is the same as :user would be)

```
 context "when logged in" do 

 before :each do
@account = Factory.create(:account)
@current_game = Factory(:game_stat)
visit login_path
    fill_in 'Username or Email Address', :with => @account.email
    fill_in 'Password', :with => @account.password
  click_button('Log in')
```

end

So factories are another matter, mine looked like this:

```
Factory.define :account do |f|
 f.sequence(:username) { |n| "ecj#{n}" }
 f.sequence(:email) { |n| "ecj#{n}@edjones.com" }
 f.password "secret"
 f.password_confirmation {|u| u.password }
```

end

You don't have to use factories, but you do need to get that session and current_user established.

Answer (score 0):

On important bit is to ensure the user is activated after creation if you're using the :user_activation submodule of Sorcery.

So, if you're using the fabrication gem, that would look like,

```
Fabricator(:properly_activated_user, :from => :user) do
  after_create { |user| user.activate! }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As @nmott mentioned you need to do two things:

1) Register text helper methods using:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails
end
```

2) In your example access `current_user` through `controller.current_user` like that:

```
login_user(user)
expect(controller.current_user).to be_present
```